# Relation between TopDocs.totalHits and parameter 'n' of Indexsearcher.search

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to find a total number of hits for a query using Lucene index( version 4.3.1).

I understood that I have to use one among the search method of https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int)

```
public TopDocs search(Query query,
             int n) - Finds the top n hits for query.
```

In the TopDocs, I can see a ***totalHits*** field
https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocs.html#totalHits

But I am not able to understand the impact of  parameter of ***’n’*** search() to ***TopDocs.totalHits***.

For eg: If I set n = 1000,  then is it TopDocs.totalHits  will be < = n ?

In one of my run I passed n = 1 but in that search TopDocs.totalHits was 29.

Can somebody please throw some light.

Answer (score 1):

> If I set n = 1000, then is it TopDocs.totalHits will be < = n ?

Yes. With "n" you define how many results you're interested in. TopDocs.totalHits reflects the effective found number of hits.

Usually it's not really useful to search for all document because it may lead to performance issues. Additional to that the user's may not interested in all results -> there's where paging or filtering takes place.

If you wanna search for all results you need to work with a Collector and this search method:

```
public void search(Query query, Collector results)
```

Based on your Collector you're able to get all searchresults or number of hits or scores of those hits.

Comment: is there any other document which specify this behavior?

Comment: what do you mean with document?

Comment: I meant like java doc. But I think your answer is not correct.  I called search()  by passing  'n' = 1 but in Topdocs.totalHits I got 29. I updated the question with this example

Comment: well the official java docs and lucene documentations. that's how i've learnt it.
wow ok that is interessting, may there is a mimimum size. have you tried with 10 for example?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Anyway I tried  with 10 still give 29 results

Comment: can you maybe provide your code? would help to analyse

Comment: the original code is part of a bigger project. I will try to create a small sample which can reproduce this but it may take some time

Comment: do problem. just try to help you :)